# FFmpeg buildpack for Heroku does not support ogg. Unknown encoder 'libvorbis'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ffmpeg

After some work, I was finally able to get the buildpack installed on Heroku. I ran into this error:

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, mono, u8, 176 kb/s

2015-10-03T01:15:59.635036+00:00 app[web.1]: -t is not an input option, 
    keeping it for the next output; consider fixing your command line.
2015-10-03T01:15:59.635055+00:00 app[web.1]: Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous
2015-10-03T01:15:59.635479+00:00 app[web.1]: Unknown encoder 'libvorbis'
```

My code is:

```
ffmpeg -t 15 -i #{current_path} -acodec libvorbis -qscale 1 #{temp_path}
```

The `-t` option is supposed to be for seconds and `libvorbis` is for ogg conversion.

`ffmpeg -version` returns this:

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-06-02-5711e4f
built on Jun 2 2013 07:38:40 with gcc 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)
configuration: --enable-shared --disable-asm --prefix=/app/vendor/ffmpeg
libavutil 52. 34.100 / 52. 34.100 libavcodec 55. 13.100 / 55. 13.100
libavformat 55. 8.102 / 55. 8.102 libavdevice 55. 2.100 / 55. 2.100
libavfilter 3. 74.101 / 3. 74.101 libswscale 2. 3.100 / 2. 3.100
libswresample 0. 17.102 / 0. 17.102
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do `heroku run rails console` in your project directory and post output of `ffmpeg -version` and `ffmpeg -codecs`.

Comment: The `ffmpeg -version` output shows why you have the libvorbis issue; ffmpeg must be compiled with `--enable-libvorbis` configuration option for it to be supported.  I suspect the `-t` option error could be caused by it being _before_ the `-i` option.  It works fine that way on my build (compiled from master a couple weeks ago), but ffmpeg can be picky about parameter ordering and has been known to break/change parameter compatibility.  I'm afraid I'm not very familiar with heroku buildpacks, but hopefully that will point you in the right direction.

Comment: FWIW, [HYPERHYPER/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg](https://github.com/HYPERHYPER/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg) states it is compiled with libvorbis support.